# Get all active Routes / Paths in a running Play application

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

Is there a standard way to get all possible (excluding wildcards of course) routes / paths valid within a play application ?

I can do it with

```
Play.current.routes.map( _.documentation.map(_._2))
```

which gives me all available routes but it looks a bit hacky to me.

Comment: This is similiar way that is used for displaying all routes when you hit 404 error in development mode.

Comment: It seems like the only way, at least as of now.

Comment: This seems to be the right way of enlisting all the routes of a Play application. Official documentation doesn't mention any such thing however.

Comment: It's notable that if you need this for client-side purposes there is a chance that `play.api.Routes.javascriptRouter` utility method could be of help.

Answer (score 2):

Just for elaboration, what I do is this ( exactly what you did ):

```
  val myroutes = Play.current.routes map (routes => routes.documentation) getOrElse (Nil)
  myroutes foreach { r =>
    println("%-10s %-50s %s".format(r._1, r._2, r._3))
  }
```

And I also get:

```
GET        /                                                  controllers.Application.index
GET        /apis                                              controllers.Application.apis
GET        /docs                                              controllers.Application.docs
GET        /sampleapi/status/$id<[^/]+>                       controllers.SampleAPI.status(id:String)
GET        /city/$id<[^/]+>                                   controllers.CityAPI.findById(id:Long)
GET        /city1/$id<[^/]+>                                  controllers.CityAPI.findById1(id:Long)
GET        /apps/authorize/                                   controllers.Apps.authorize
POST       /apps/send_auth/                                   controllers.Apps.send_auth
GET        /clients/                                          controllers.Clients.list
GET        /client/new                                        controllers.Clients.create
POST       /client/add                                        controllers.Clients.add
POST       /client/update                                     controllers.Clients.update
GET        /client/edit/$id<[^/]+>                            controllers.Clients.edit(id:String)
PUT        /client/                                           controllers.Clients.update
GET        /client/$id<[^/]+>                                 controllers.Clients.get(id:String)
DELETE     /client/$id<[^/]+>                                 controllers.Clients.delete(id:String)
GET        /login                                             controllers.Auth.login
POST       /authenticate                                      controllers.Auth.authenticate
GET        /logout                                            controllers.Auth.logout
POST       /oauth2/access_token                               controllers.OAuth2Controller.accessToken
GET        /webjars/$file<.+>                                 controllers.WebJarAssets.at(file:String)
GET        /assets/$file<.+>                                  controllers.Assets.at(path:String = "/public", file:String)
```

This also includes webjar and assets path, so you may want to filter them out.